# Get currency name from Locale swift

Tags: swift, locale, currency

Is there any way to get a currency name from the current Locale in swift? I'm not talking about the identifier or symbol (so not the "USD" or "$"). I'm looking for something like "American Dollars". Is that built in to swift or do I have to make my own list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality is accessible on `Locale`:

```
let locale = Locale.current
print(locale.localizedString(forCurrencyCode: "USD")) // Optional("US Dollar")
```